# Поставать фамилию в творительный падеж (с кем?)

Tags: падежи

Александр Понамарев - с кем? С Александром Понамарев(*м)? Как правильно изменить окончание фамилии, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

Фамилии на ОВ/ЕВ и ИН/ЫН склоняются как прилагательные, поэтому: с Александром Пономарёвым (каким).

Для сравнения: с поэтом Пушкиным (окончание прилагательного), но: под городом Пушкином (окончание существительного).

Comment: Ну, в нашем случае: с Александром ПонАмАревым

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать без имени: дружил с  Ивановым, Петровым, ПонАмАревым.

Comment: Я бы в данном контексте пошел еще дальше : с Александром ПАнАмАрЁвым)  
Панама + рёв = (малыш в панамке плачет)...

Comment: Тоже вариант)